# How to expand multidimensional numpy arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a multidimensional numpy array of following shape
`(80, 755, 6)`

that can be interpreted as 80 timeseries each of them contains 755 elements (time points/rows) consisting of 6 values (features). Now I want to extend the number of features to 8 features.
The two new features are fixed values of type string and int. At the end for each observed values of the features I want to add the new features in the list for example this is one oberved list of features

```
[0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5, 0.6]
```

that I want to extend with fixed values like this

```
[28,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5, 0.6, "Door"]
```

for all observations in each time series so that at the end I end with an numpy array of shape `(80, 755, 8)`. How would I do that the fastest way?

Comment: Create an array with shape (80,755,2) with the desired values, and `concatenate` on axis 2.  But be careful about using mixed int and string values.  That will turn the whole thing into strings.  `numpy` arrays have a uniform `dtype` (unless you get into structured arrays).

Comment: Play with a small sample array before wasting time trying to find the "fastest" way.

Comment: Just use `hstack`

Comment: `hstack` concatenates on axis=1